# How to get an element's property in WebKitGTK?

Tags: dom, webkit, webkitgtk

I want to get an element's property (for instance, `value`) in WebKitGTK. I can easily get an *attribute*, and I can also get some properties of some types by using e.g. `webkit_dom_html_input_element_get_value`, but is there a general way of getting any property of any element which has that property?